# How do I create two buttons to stop and start a clock?

Tags: php, twitter, timer, clock

im just starting off working on a twitter app for local sports scores, and I need a few buttons that automatically tweet that;
the match has kicked off
half time
2nd half
full time.

How do I do this?

(noobie question, i'm sorry, but gotta start somewhere, right?)

Comment: It is pretty hard to to this automatically, because the lengths of the two halves are variable. So you cannot, for example, attach a timer and call some functions at certain time....

Comment: Buttons will be created in HTML, not PHP. Do you want to know [how to send a tweet from PHP](http://www.brownphp.com/2009/01/use-php-to-twitter-your-tweets/) or how to send an HTML-form or how to read the button-values within PHP?

Comment: It's not that hard to do automatically, two crons in my opinion. One to parse a feed, and cache sends (and prevent dupes) and the second the sender.

Answer (score 0):

This will be hard to do automatically because you can't guess when halftime will be because sports times has too many variables. What you can do however is create a script that you can text-e-mail to your server  that will automatically do that based on what text you do it in real time.. but then if you go that far .. you might as well just use twitter text version and u can just write it like that lol

Comment: Sorry to be a real noob, but I don't think I explained it very well. Let me try again.

Comment: I need to create a few buttons that just tweet the words "Kick Off", "Half Time", "Second Half" and "Full Time". As for the clock part of it, i might consider that later, but just need a button when pressed, it tweets the corresponding text. Again, thanks for the responses, and sorry for being a noob here. Actually, Anybody wanna help me out an make some money while they're at it?